# 2D Array Maze Generation

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, maze, ascii-art

So I am generating a maze and I have a 4 bit code that indicates which walls are present/destroyed.

Each index of my array will have a 3x3 box depending on the 4 bit code.

The problem I am running into is when I fill the index with the box I am forced to use the newline character (in order to make a 3x3 box) and that completely screws up my output.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just draw all the cells of a row in one go.

Comment: Wouldn't the new line characters in the first 3x3 mess up the rest of the row? @tobias_k

Comment: No, because there is no newline character. You draw the first row of cells, by printing all the first lines of all the cells, _then a newline_, then all the second lines, and so on.

Comment: Yeah that's my last resort, but I am trying to see if theres a way I can print the 3x3 right away.

Comment: That is the nature of ascii text. You have to draw things line by line.

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing that. Wasn't too bad, just requires some extra thinking.